# GitHub with IntelliJ (commit)

Tags: github, intellij-idea, commit

Anyone can help me? I try commit my project but that no working.. (traditional git with terminal is working, but i rather intellij) ...

[info from intellij - invalid vcs root maping / cannot run git ( file not found)]

[file not found git.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNUTj.png)

[invalid vcs root mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbI58.png)

Answer (score 1):

It appears git.exe is not accessible via the PATH variable in the IntelliJ context. You need to specify the explicit path to git executable in the Settings | Version Control | Git.

The mapping issue usually occurs when there is no `.git` folder in the folder that is mapped as a git root in settings. Make sure the correct path to your git repository is mapped.

Such issues could also be cause by some specific git configuration, e.g. if you have GIT_DIR variable set that point to some incorrect place.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu / Debian users:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

IntelliJ then "saw it" after I did this. (No intelliJ settings changes needed)